# Problems with create-react-kotlin-app and backend

Tags: javascript, kotlin, create-react-app

### Question

I want to deploy my application on the server in production but I am struggling to do so.

When I use `npm run build` to produce an "Optimized" version of the app and launch it with `serve`, it doesn't seem to use the proxy.

Going back to the dev server with npm start, I get this error:

> TypeError: Kotlin.defineModule is not a function

I cannot get out of this. Has someone got a similar configuration? How did you make it work in production? Do you use something to proxy the requests to your backend?

### App configuration

**Frontend**:

Web app using create-react-kotlin-app in kotlin, react. It's on `localhost:3000` (dev-server) and has a proxy to `localhost:3001` (the backend).

**Backend**

Backend, which is a simple express router for auth and data managment from the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you provide a better structure to your question, the question becomes easier to read and more people will take time to think about possible solutions. It's also good to start with the question as the reader will then be able to read the rest of your post with an understanding of what is causing you problems.

Comment: One problem, I found out, is a bug in their side: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CRKA-66

Comment: To fix just delete "ROOT_PROJECT"/node_modules/.cache

Comment: So where you able to fix your problem? Please add an answer to your own question with your details that fixed the problem and mark it as a solution. Thanks and great to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go back and answer my question,

One is a bug on their side:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CRKA-66

I'm using a config that maybe is not ideal:

I copy the build folder that contains the optimized folder into the backend and I serve the main view "index.html" as an entry point using sendFile().

I then use the url and args to route the user into various react components pages, maybe in the future it's best to switch to: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

according with the repo [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app/#npm-start-or-yarn-start), if you are getting `Kotlin.defineModule is not a function` you would need to run:

```
rm -rf node_modules/.cache
```